# how to see GlassFish running on EC2 RedHat linux machine?

Tags: unix, glassfish, amazon-ec2, redhat

I setup a RedHat 6.1 linux machine on Amazon EC2.  I installed JDK 1.7 and GlassFish.  I started GlassFish, seems to be running because when I wget localhost:8080 it "downloads" a index.html file.

I added 8080 to the "inbound" list in the EC2 security group that's assigned to the machine.

When I try and access it in a web browser using the name they gave me, like so:

```
http://ec2-107-20-73-68.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080
```

I get nothing.

Maybe I'm supposed to open port 8080 on the linux box?

Is it something I did wrong in EC2?  Or is it something I did wrong in RedHat?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run jps from the command line to verify the instance is running. You'll see "PELaunch" if it is.

From there you need to try the admin page (or try it first) http://ec2-107-20-73-68.compute-1.amazonaws.com:4848/login.jsf

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points here:

1. Yes, you'll have to open up the public-facing ports (that's why localhost:8080 works but inbound does not).
2. Keep in mind that GlassFish Server 3.1.1+ supports JDK 7.  We haven't tested earlier versions.  I don't think this is your problem, but hopefully this will help avoid potential future issues.

Some useful URL for opening up a port (hint, run ec2-authorize):
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1233

Hope this helps!